# What does a [,] parameter mean when defined in a function in the pandas documentation?

Tags: python, pandas

If there is a function defined in the pandas docs as: function([,parameter]) what does this represent and where can I find this information in the docs? I would like to know for the future if there is a conventional place for documentation to explain their notation choices.

Comment: Something like tab + enter perhaps ? But I guess there are several reasons why this question is off topic

Comment: Please don't edit a question to transform it into a completely unrelated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this would be phrased as

```
function(a[, b])
```

which simply means that the function can be called either with one argument as `function(a)` or with two arguments as `function(a, b)`. `[]` is standard notation for "optional", while including the `,` in the brackets makes it clear that the comma would need to accompany that optional argument.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the thorough answer.